# problem with calculating inverse function in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have already calculated some generators for generating sublattices .I also wrote a code for extracting all generators which includes:

```
for i=1:12
for j=1:3
G_SUB_A3_N1(j,:,i)=A3_ii33G33( A3_ijk33G33(i,j),:);
end
end
```

I have 12 generators furthermore all of them has 3 column.
my problem is that i want compute my matrix which my definition is:
t=inv(G_SUB_A3_N1)*one specific generator

I have already written this code for doing that:

```
for i=1:12
for j=1:3
t (j,:,i)=  inv( G_SUB_A3_N1(i,j),:)*G34;
end
end
```

I want to do t=inv(G_SUB_A3_N1)*one specific generator for whole 12 generator and my code which is shown in above ,said that we do not have inv variable .inv is inverse function .
i do not  have any idea for tackling this problem.

Comment: Do you have another script inside your working directory named inv.m? Also, you have `inv(matrix, :)`. What are you trying to do? It should be `inv(G_SUB_A3_N1(i,j))`.

Comment: On a side note: computing the inverse of a matrix in a computer is a bad idea, and there is almost always an alternative to doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using this code it worked.

```
for i=1:12
tN1 (:,:,i)=  inv( G_SUB_A3_N1(:,:,i))*G34;
 c=c+1;
  end
```